Pipline Failed : ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
I have added jest for unit test in my react native app, to automate testing in gitlab I added following yml file to the project.
stages:
  - test

unit-test:
  image: node:latest
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm run test:ci
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
      - test-results/ 
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - junit.xml

unit tests are passing without any issues but pipeline is failing with following error,
Uploading artifacts...
coverage/: found 27 matching artifact files and directories 
WARNING: test-results/: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/...) 
WARNING: Upload request redirected                  location=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/7924704281/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive new-url=https://gitlab.com
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=request redirected
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=7924704281 responseStatus=201 Created token=glcbt-66
Uploading artifacts...
junit.xml: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 
WARNING: Upload request redirected                  location=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/7924704281/artifacts?artifact_format=gzip&artifact_type=junit new-url=https://gitlab.com
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=request redirected
Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=7924704281 responseStatus=201 Created token=glcbt-66
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Can someone help me to fix this issue, I'm beginner to this
